# cannot load HelloWorld example in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

I am new with PhoneGap and I am using it for android. I am following step-by-step the tutorial HelloPhoneGap from http://phonegap.com/start/#android. at first run it it runs ok, but later-on when I run it i got this error:

logcat:

```
03-21 09:52:02.467: D/dalvikvm(534): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-21 09:52:04.738: W/System.err(534): =====================================================================================
03-21 09:52:04.738: W/System.err(534): ERROR: plugin.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.
03-21 09:52:04.738: W/System.err(534): https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/res/xml/plugins.xml
03-21 09:52:04.738: W/System.err(534): =====================================================================================
03-21 09:52:04.738: W/ResourceType(534): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
03-21 09:52:04.748: D/AndroidRuntime(534): Shutting down VM
03-21 09:52:04.748: W/dalvikvm(534): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-21 09:52:04.758: W/System.err(534): java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-21 09:52:04.768: W/System.err(534):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:573)
03-21 09:52:04.768: W/System.err(534):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
03-21 09:52:04.768: W/System.err(534):  at java.net.PlainServerSocketImpl.create(PlainServerSocketImpl.java:38)
03-21 09:52:04.778: W/System.err(534):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:98)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:69)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  at org.apache.cordova.CallbackServer.run(CallbackServer.java:208)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:558)
03-21 09:52:04.788: W/System.err(534):  ... 6 more
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phonegap.helloworld/com.phonegap.helloworld.app}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:907)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:82)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:62)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap$1.run(DroidGap.java:502)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4170)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.loadUrlIntoView(DroidGap.java:478)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.loadUrl(DroidGap.java:444)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at com.phonegap.helloworld.app.onCreate(app.java:15)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-21 09:52:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  ... 11 more
```

console:

```
[2012-03-21 09:49:28 - HelloPhoneGap] ------------------------------
[2012-03-21 09:49:28 - HelloPhoneGap] Android Launch!
[2012-03-21 09:49:28 - HelloPhoneGap] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-21 09:49:28 - HelloPhoneGap] Performing com.phonegap.helloworld.app activity launch
[2012-03-21 09:49:28 - HelloPhoneGap] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avd'
[2012-03-21 09:49:28 - HelloPhoneGap] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd'
[2012-03-21 09:49:39 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Connection refused
[2012-03-21 09:49:39 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-03-21 09:49:39 - Emulator] 
[2012-03-21 09:49:41 - HelloPhoneGap] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-03-21 09:49:41 - HelloPhoneGap] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-03-21 09:51:23 - HelloPhoneGap] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-21 09:51:23 - HelloPhoneGap] Uploading HelloPhoneGap.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-21 09:51:24 - HelloPhoneGap] Installing HelloPhoneGap.apk...
[2012-03-21 09:52:02 - HelloPhoneGap] Success!
[2012-03-21 09:52:02 - HelloPhoneGap] Starting activity com.phonegap.helloworld.app on device emulator-5554
[2012-03-21 09:52:04 - HelloPhoneGap] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.phonegap.helloworld/.app }
```

can anyone can help me about my case?

Comment: "It seems your `plugin.xml` is missing. Download that file from [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob_plain;f=framework/res/xml/plugins.xml) and put it in   `res/xml/plugins.xml`." That's what the error says. Have you tried that?

Comment: thanks zapl for the reply.. it helps me. now i can see my hello world working ^_^ ..

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me was to copy the file 'config.xml' from the Cordova download zip (lib/android/example/res/xml/config.xml) into my project's res/xml folder.  I ran into this same error, working through the Cordova 2.0.0 Getting Started with Android page.  The file plugin.xml does not appear to be in Cordova 2.0.0 (at least in the Android branch).  The error to logcat still mentions it however.

Comment: I am getting the same error but still it says `CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!`

Answer (score 1):

1) In onCreate method did you initialize like **super.init();** if not do 
2) check plugins present in this path "**xml/res/plugins.xml**" if not [find plugins here](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/phonegap/res/xml/plugins.xml?r=99)
   Note: put that plugins tag inside cordova like `<cordova> <plugins> <plugin> </plugins> </cordova>`